# How do we prove that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^{2}}$ converges to $0$ by the definition?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I want to prove by definition that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{x+1}{x^2}=0$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\neq 0$, I have to find $A>0$ such that $x>A\Rightarrow \left|\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right|<\varepsilon$

So I have  that $\left|\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right|<\left|\frac1x +\frac{1}{x^2}\right|=\left|\frac1x\right|\left|1+\frac1x\right|$

but i don't know how to continue ?

Comment: How about $A=\max(2/\varepsilon,\sqrt{2/\varepsilon})\,?$

Comment: how i can get this ? @KurtG.

Comment: Atila Correia's answer leads to this. How must you choose his $M$ such that $1/M+1/M^2$ is below $\varepsilon$?

Comment: i solve the inequality !

Comment: Sounds like you've dunnit.

Comment: @KurtG. no i don't understand your answer

Comment: Ok. So when you want $1/M+1/M^2<\varepsilon$ you can demand that $M$ shall be such that $1/M<\varepsilon/2$ and $1/M^2<\varepsilon/2\,.$ Does $M=\max(2/\varepsilon,\sqrt{2/\varepsilon})$ satisfy those two conditions?

Comment: yes, but we often solve the equation i.e we majorat $\frac1x+\frac{1}{x^2}$ after that we get M, we don't replace x by M and find M

Comment: Sounds like you accept that we have the lower bound for $M$ now. If $x>M$ then we clearly have $1/x+1/x^2<\varepsilon$ also. Now look at Atila's last line in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\neq 0$, i have to find $A>0$ such that
> $~ \displaystyle x>A\Rightarrow \left|\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right|<\varepsilon$

Alternative approach:

To achieve a linear constraint between $A$ and $\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$, I will place a lower bound on $A$.  
I will arbitrarily require that $A$ be $\geq 10.$

This constraint, coupled with the constraint that $x > A,$ implies that
$~ \dfrac{x+1}{x} < \dfrac{11}{10}.$

Further, since $x > 0$, I know that

$$\left| ~\frac{x+1}{x^2} ~\right| = \frac{x+1}{x^2} < \frac{11}{10x}
< \frac{11}{10A}.$$

So, the goal is achieved if

- $A \geq 10$.
- $\displaystyle \frac{11}{10A} \leq \varepsilon \iff A \geq \frac{11}{10\varepsilon}.$

So, the following constraint works:

$$A = \max\left(10, ~\frac{11}{10\epsilon} \right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Then we can consider the definition:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists M\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in X)(x > M \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

In the present case, suppose that $x > M > 0$. Hence we may claim that:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x + 1}{x^{2}} - 0\right| & = \left|\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right| = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^{2}} < \frac{1}{M} + \frac{1}{M^{2}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: A further hint for OP: by choosing $M>1$, the final inequality can be simplified one step further.

Comment: i must solve the inequality $\frac{M+1}{M^2}<\varepsilon$ that is $M^2\varepsilon -M-1>0$ ? is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $x\mapsto\frac{x+1}{x^2}$ is positive and decreasing on $\Bbb R_+,$ so the "best" (i.e. smallest) $A$ is the positive solution of
$$\frac{A+1}{A^2}=\varepsilon,$$
i.e.
$$A=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\varepsilon}}{2\varepsilon}.$$